# SQL left outer join, groupby & orderby to LINQ method query or method syntax

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, join

The main objective is to return a list of ingredients in a sorted order according to popularity (which is indicated by how many people have as their favorite a particular ingredient).  The SQL equivalent is below:

```
select distinct COUNT(PersonalInfoes.FavoriteIngredient_ID) as NoUsing, 
Ingredients.Name 
from PersonalInfoes  right join Ingredients
on PersonalInfoes.FavoriteIngredient_ID = Ingredients.ID
group by Ingredients.Name
order by NoUsing desc
```

What is the equivalent SQL query of method syntax that will produce the same result as above?
The closest I've got is this:

```
from i in db.Ingredients 
join p in db.PersonalInfos on i.ID equals p.FavoriteIngredient.ID into ing
from p in ing.DefaultIfEmpty()
group i by i.Name into g
from p in g
orderby g.Count() descending
select new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }.Name;
```

Comment: What is the problem that you still have with that code?

Comment: It still doesnt work, it doesnt sort according to the count of the number of people who uses each ingredient

Comment: It will be quite difficult for me to help without having access to a database where you have the problem (maybe somebody else can write the LINQ without it, but not me). Is there a way you can isolate the problem into something we can run on any system?

Comment: The data is just coming from two tables.  1 Table is called PersonalInfo w/ the ff fields: string Firstname, string Lastname, datetime Birthdate, int ID, string email, ingredient Favorite Ingredient.  Favorite Ingredient is a complex data type of type ingredient.  Ingredient corresponds to the OTHER table: Ingredient w/ the ff fields: string Name and int ID

Answer (score 2):

Your query does a left outer join to include ingredients with no favorites.  The problem is, for each ingredient with no favorites, you are counting the single value that gets produced by DefaultIfEmpty().  You can exclude the default values when counting like this:

`orderby g.Count(x => x != null) descending`

You actually don't have to perform a left join.  You can just sum the counts of the groups from your group join:

```
from i in db.Ingredients 
join p in db.PersonalInfos on i.ID equals p.FavoriteIngredient.ID into faves
group faves.Count() by i.Name into faveCounts
let count = faveCounts.Sum()
orderby count descending
select new { Name = faveCounts.Key, Count = count };
```

A subjective problem with your code is it's very confusing with all of the `group by` and `from` clauses.  If you find this to be an issue, you can try using more descriptive names, using subqueries, or using method syntax.

**Edit:** Here is a method syntax version.  It is not a direct conversion from the query syntax version because that would be quite ugly.

```
db.Ingredients
  .GroupJoin(db.PersonalInfos,
             i => i.ID,
             p => p.ID, 
             (i, g) => new { i.Name, FaveCount = g.Count() })
  .GroupBy(x => x.Name,
           (key, grp) => new { Name = key, Count = grp.Sum(y => y.FaveCount) })
  .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count);
```

Comment: I understand.  Thanks Risky Martin.

Comment: Btw can you give me the method syntax of your solution above?

Comment: btw, here there is p=>p.id (the personalinfo row) but then how come in the following line it becomes g.count, what does g represent?  The count of people who chooses a particular ingredient? how did you say that you mean to count the favorite ingredient field?

Comment: @Nizzy: `p => p.ID` is for selecting which field of a PersonalInfo to join on, while g has the PersonalInfos that got group joined with an Ingredient i.